# php: additional output from foreach of array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

i'm trying to refresh my memory of OO & array structure. i have,

```
class room{
            private $people = array(
                'name' => array(
                            'height' => null,
                            'age' => null
                        )
            );

            function set($list){
                foreach($list as $person){
                    $this->people[$person['name']]['height'] = $person['height'];
                    $this->people[$person['name']]['age'] = $person['age'];
                }        
            }

            function print(){
                foreach($this->people as $k => $v){
                    echo $k . "<br>";
                    echo $v['height'] . ":" . $v['age'] . "<br><br>";
                }
            }
        }

        $input = array( array('name' => 'John', 'height' => '6.4', 'age' => '20'),
                        array('name' => 'Jane', 'height' => '5.2', 'age' => '21')
            );
        $i = new room;
        $i->set($input);
        $i->print();
```

the output is,

```
name
:

John
6.4:20

Jane
5.2:21
```

i'm confused as why `name :` appears first, when the input array only contains 2 values of each person. i am unsure if i am using my arrays correctly, could someone point out my mistake?

My overall aim of this is to have correct understanding of arrays within arrays & how to best set & get the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've initialised the `$people` array to contain those values

```
private $people = array(
    'name' => array(
        'height' => null,
        'age' => null
     )
);
```

Change it to:

```
private $people = array();
```

Comment: Resolved! i forget that you don't have to define an array in php

Comment: i have a 10 minute wait that is preventing me from doing so at the moment :)

Comment: you answered too quickly for stackoverflow :P

Answer (score 1):

that's the good way to do it
your people class

```
class people {

    //properties
        private $name;
        private $height;
        private $age;

    //setters
        public function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        public function setHeight($height) {
            $this->height = $height;
        }

        public function setAge($age) {
            $this->age = $age;
        }

    //getters
        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        public function getHeight() {
            return $this->height;
        }

        public function getAge() {
            return $this->age;
        }

    }
```

your room class

```
    class room {

    //properties
        private $people = array();

    //setters
        public function setPeople($people) {
            $this->people[] = $people;
        }

    //getters
        public function getPeoples() {
            return $this->people;
        }

    }
```

and how to control it in OOP

```
    $people1 = new people();

    $people1->setName('John');
    $people1->setHeight('6.4');
    $people1->setAge('20');

    $people2 = new people();

    $people2->setName('Jane');
    $people2->setHeight('5.2');
    $people2->setAge('21');

    $room = new room();

    $room->setPeople($people1);
    $room->setPeople($people2);
```

Answer (score 0):

// Removing people array initial data will solve the issue :)

class room{
            private $people = array();

```
        function set($list){
            foreach($list as $person){
                $this->people[$person['name']]['height'] = $person['height'];
                $this->people[$person['name']]['age'] = $person['age'];
            }        
        }

        function print(){
            foreach($this->people as $k => $v){
                echo $k . "<br>";
                echo $v['height'] . ":" . $v['age'] . "<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }

    $input = array( array('name' => 'John', 'height' => '6.4', 'age' => '20'),
                    array('name' => 'Jane', 'height' => '5.2', 'age' => '21')
        );
    $i = new room;
    $i->set($input);
    $i->print();
```